# JSchException: Auth fail on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, gradle, ssh, jsch

I recently changed my cloud server OS from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
After that, remote upload jar task fail during gradle build using org.hidetake.ssh with below message.

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

I guess it could be a RSA problem which is deprecated on Ubuntu 22.04 but I can't find how to resolve it.

The config I'm used with ssh.run task is below. I would really appreciate if anyone has idea.

```
remotes {
    myServer {
        host = 'x.x.x.x'
        port = 22
        user = 'ubuntu'
        identity = file('d:/a.pem') 
        knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's indeed quite likely that the server requires `rsa-sha2`. JSch does not support it. And as JSch seems not to be updated anymore, it quite likely never will.

There's a fork of JSch that does though:
https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

---

Another (less secure obviously) option is to reconfigure the server not to require the `rsa-sha2` by adding *deprecated* `ssh-rsa` to [`PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms).